# How to put website to maintenance mode without killing the current transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, web-deployment

We need to put an e-commerce website to maintenance mode for about 20 minutes. How can we do this without killing the current transactions? Because, there are almost always some people who are placing some orders.

What are the steps? Or we need to write some kind of script or a small piece of software to handle this?

Comment: Can you do the maintenance on a separate deployment and then sync the data from the 20 minutes into the new deployment and switch the url?

Comment: what happens for example one person just clicked on a "Place order" button and was waiting the page to place the order and reload? does it hurt? or not?

Comment: because IIS is going to be restarted anyways and app pool will be recycled, so user will lose the focus and I think the transaction will be lost.

Comment: It depends on how you have implemented transactions. Do you have some kind of reversal process? The transaction will get corrupted if you switch the sites right at the time when someone places an order, yes.

Comment: we have used Authorize.net for payment processing. The remote response time is about 2 sec. if a transaction is killed between those 2 seconds, we cannot process the response from authorize.net, and transaction will be placed on authorize side but not on our side. so user will be withdrawal some money but he will never get shipped.

Comment: Check with authorize.net which payments went through and manually make the changes to your system or refund the payments with authorize.net.

Answer (score 0):

*To answer your specific question:*

With such a long maintenance window you'll want to implement a burn-down period yourself. Set a flag to enter a type of soon-to-be-maintenance mode.

During this period don't allow new users to log in (i.e., if not already logged in/have session, show maintenance mode message).

For existing users show them a warning that the system is about to go into maintenance mode. As a good precaution you can keep track of active session count as users hit the server in the soon-to-be-maintenance mode and have an internal admin page that shows this count to inform when you're users are ready for you to go into maintenance mode.

*However,*

I would encourage you to look into why you need to put the site into maintenance mode for 20 minutes. This seems a bit unusual. Could you perhaps achieve the desired goal with Blue/Green deployments?

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html